# Is there a way to specify names of tabs?

Tags: org-mode, buffers, tabbar

I'm using [denote](https://protesilaos.com/emacs/denote), which produces quite long file names. E.g. `20230410T021830--title-i-gave-to-the-org-file__tag1_tag2_tab3_tag4.org`. I also use tabs to navigate between buffers (mainly org files).

The issue is that denotes file names are so long that only one tab (or maximum 2 tabs) can be displayed on a window.

So I was wondering how it could be possible to change the tab name without changing the file name.

I use centaur-tab but the provided solution might refer to any other package (tabbar, moody, etc.)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabs

Comment: @Drew, thx for the tag edit. Though about the title edit, my question isn't limited to tabbar. It concerns any implementation of tabs in Emacs.

Comment: I think your question is about the tabbar, not `TAB` characters. If not, please clarify what you're asking. Browser-like tabs are completely different animals from `TAB` characters (aka Control-I chars).

Comment: Indeed my question is not about `TAB` characters (which is why you did well to remove the `tabs` tag. However, it is not limited to tabbar, which is an implementation of browser-like tabs in Emacs, there are other implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can specify the buffer name (and consequently the tab name) of a given org file by putting the following snippet at the bottom of this file:

```
* Local Variables :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# eval: (rename-buffer "foo")
# End:
```

Besides, the new optional `denote-rename-buffer.el` provides a minor mode to automatically rename the buffer of an existing file, such that it reflects the file’s TITLE field. Users must enable `denote-rename-buffer-mode`.

See [Denote buffers can have shorter names](https://protesilaos.com/codelog/2023-07-21-denote-2-0-0/) and [Automatically rename Denote buffers](https://protesilaos.com/emacs/denote#h:3ca4db16-8f26-4d7d-b748-bac48ae32d69)

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a way to specify names of tabs without changing the file names currently edited in this tabs?*

What you see in the Tab Bar as tab labels text is *usually* the name of the currently edited *buffer*.

It is sure a bit confusing coincidence that the tab label text, the name of the buffer and the name of the in this buffer edited file are the same caused by the fact that the buffer name is set to the file name on loading a file into a buffer and the fact that the tab label text is set to the name of the current buffer.

An exception from this rule is when you explicit change the name of the tab using `M-x tab-rename` (which changes also the tabs explicit-name setting `(explicit-name . t)` to t . In this case the tab label will show always the name you set it to, no matter what buffer you are viewing in the tab.

Knowing this above you stop to worry that changing the tabs label text will also change the file name, because changing the text shown in the tab label has no impact on the edited file name.

To say it with your own words from your comment to your own answer:

> The standard behavior is that tab names rely on buffer names, and buffer names rely on file names. Though tab names can be decorrelated from buffer names and buffer names from file names.

To summarize what is stated above you have two different options for changing the text shown as tabs label:

1. changing the name of the buffer using `M-x rename-buffer`
2. changing the name of the tab using `M-x tab-rename`

Changing the name of the buffer (1.) has the advantage that the tab keeps the ability to change its label when you choose to work on another buffer mirroring this change.

Changing the name of the tab (2.) has the advantage that you can specify a kind of grouping name for all the buffers you work on in this tab and the tab name won't change if you switch to editing another buffer.

To make the changes in the names to persist between Emacs sessions use
`(desktop-save-mode 1)` in your Emacs initialization file.

---

In order to deepen your understanding  of what is shown in the tab you can use:
`M-x eval-expression` -> Eval : `(assq 'explicit-name (tab-bar--current-tab))` to check the setting of the current tabs `explicit-name` which will be `(explicit-name . t)` with an explicit set and shown name or `(explicit-name)` otherwise.

---

P.S. Credits go to *Maxim Kim* for mentioning how to rename tabs in his answer.

Comment: See the updated answer which is now considering the Maxim Kim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something obvious? There is `M-x tab-rename RET`:

[image]

Furthermore, in Mastering Emacs there is a chapter about Tab based workflows that includes an interesting example about putting org-related buffers into a separate tab-group: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/demystifying-emacs-window-manager

Search for `Tab-Based Workflows` there:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Currently, I use `centaur-tabs`, and `tab-rename` doesn't seem to have any effect on tabs. I will try to use tab-bar-mode to see how the solution you mentioned works.

Answer (score 0):

Given a file named `myfile.org`, by default when `myfile.org` is open, `myfile.org` is displayed as its tab name.

It is because by default tab names inherit buffer names and buffer names inherit file names.

So if you want to have a tab called `mytab` while keeping `myfile.org` as its associated file name, you have two options:

1. To change the buffer name associated with `myfile.org` (`M-x rename-buffer RET mytab`)
2. To change the tab name associated with `myfile.org` (`M-x tab-rename RET mytab`)

The first option will work for any Emacs tab management implementation.

The second won't. For example, it will work with Tab Bar Mode, but not with centaur-tabs.

In both cases, `mytab` association to `myfile.org` will be lost when your Emacs session is over. So, when you restart Emacs, `myfile.org` tab name will be back to `myfile.org`.

Here is [some code](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76849/how-to-automatically-trigger-a-function-according-to-an-option-mentioned-in-an-o/76850#76850) that will allow you to specify a tab name only once: With `#+buffername: mytab` in `myfile.org`'s header, you'll have `mytab` as a tab name each time you open `myfile.org`.

This code is relatvie option 1, but you can replace `rename-buffer` by `tab-rename` in it if you prefer option 2 (also replace `"buffername"` by `"tabname"` to use `#+tabname: mytab`).

Comment: Nice to see that you have in between dissolved your confusion (as I have dissolved mine too). See my answer which tries to say just that.

Comment: It seems that you don't need any programming to achieve what you are after if you save the desktop configuration and reload it on next Emacs start.