# How to automatically trigger a function according to an option mentioned in an org file header?

Tags: org-mode, buffers

Suppose I want to create an option called `#+buffername:`, so that each time the option is mentioned in an org buffer, Emacs trigger a function according to its value.

For example, if I create a file called `myfile.org`, and that I add `#+buffername: newname` in its header. How could I do to have its buffer renamed `newname`, each time I open `myfile.org`?

Comment: Are you already using `(desktop-save-mode 1)` and `(save-place-mode t)` in your Emacs initialization file?

Comment: Yes, I am already using desktop-save-mode.

Comment: If you are using this mode, how does it come that renamed buffers do not stay renamed in the next Emacs session? See my answer to your other question for hints how to find out what goes wrong. The `.emacs.desktop` file stores the changed buffer name for use in the next Emacs session.

Comment: I use this mode on rare occasions, I tweaked it to save some projects. I guess it might keep track of changed buffer names, I didn't test it.

Comment: `desktop-save-mode` does not help if you save the file and kill the buffer. The buffer does not exist any longer and cannot be remembered in a desktop file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `org-mode-hook` function to take care of that. To get the value you can simply search for the keyword, and rename the buffer if the keyword was found, e.g. as follows:

```lisp
(defun org-get-kw-value (kw)
  "Get the value of keyword KW."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((case-fold-search t))
      (re-search-forward (format "^#\\+%s:\\(.+\\)" kw) nil t)
      (when-let (kwval (match-string-no-properties 1))
        (string-trim kwval)))))

(defun my-org-hook-function ()
  "If keyword BUFFERNAME exists, set buffer-name to its value."
  (when-let (new-buf-name (org-get-kw-value "buffername"))
    (rename-buffer new-buf-name)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-hook-function)
```

Alternatively, you could use the [org-element-api](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) to find the keyword and its value, but the regex search is simpler and faster.

Comment: You might want a case-insensitive search for the keyword (I believe they are supposed to be recognized whatever the case of each character in the name - but I should probably check the syntax doc to make sure).

Comment: Thank you it works quite well, except that I have an error message each time I open an org file that doesn't contain `#+buffername:`. `File mode specification error: (search-failed ^#\+buffername:\(.+\))`

Comment: It needs a `save-excursion`, a fix in `re-search-forward` to not raise errors if there is no match and a check to return the match or `nil` if there is no match. The caller will also have to be modified to check for `nil`.

Comment: aargh I can't manage to do all that (T⌓T)

Comment: @NickD Thanks! Looks good to me...

Comment: Tested lightly - seems to work. There was no need to change the caller, just `org-kw-value`.

Comment: Thank you @NickD! I was not able to understand the `when-let` syntax. Didn't find any documentation that could help me understand these two lines...

Comment: `C-h f when-let` should give you basic information: it's basically a combination of `when` and `let`: it binds variables (like `let` does) and if all of them are non-nil, it evaluates the body. In `org-get-kw-value` it binds `kwval` to the match and if it is non-nil (i.e. there *was* a match), it trims the value and returns it (otherwise the `when-let` returns nil, just like `when` does when the condition is false).

Comment: I noticed that with this hook I'm unable to use `#+INCLUDE:`. Each time I try to export an org file containing `#+INCLUDE:`, even if none of the concerned files have their buffer name modified, I have the following error: `match-string-no-properties: Args out of range: #<killed buffer>`. Any clue why and if it is solvable?